# how to run automation in Multiple machine

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

I am doing automation using selenium and java in Eclipse. I have got a scenario to create registration of 1000 user for which my automation is taking 1 minute per registration. What I want is, how to run automation in different VM's using my machine as hub to reduce the time?   I got solution of these using Selenium grid concept. But how to configure multiple node? with examples?

Comment: I would actually start by trying to understand why it's taking a whole minute for registration, and trying to bring that figure down.

Comment: Thanks Joe, But my registration page is having too many fields to be filled. So timing is not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use as examle two diff cmd instance to create two nod for runing ur test in diff machine form one hub machine

This link may help you :- http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2016/04/running-multiple-nodes-of-selenium-grid.html

http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2016/02/selenium-grid-2-configuration-setup-hub.html